# Windows 7: run powershell v2 from start menu's run command

Tags: windows-7, powershell

When I open Start menu in Windows 7 and press Run and then write "Powershell" the powershell v1 starts. How to start powershell v2 using the same invoking method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 ships with Powershell 2.0. Are you certain that you are running version 1? To confirm run this $PSVersionTable inside the power shell.

Here is the output from my machine:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings\saziz> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3603
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: Interesting. When typing "Powershell" in the little search box within the start menu, the new Powershell (blue background, large window) starts; from Win+R a "DOS-Box-like" window opens that displays the path `...\PowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` - but both are actually the same version. Just look different...

Comment: Yes, it seems to be 2.0 version although the path says that this is version 1.0

Comment: PowerShell 2.0 replaces 1.0.  Originally the PS team planned for possible incompatibilities, that is why the script extensions are also .ps1.

Answer (score 0):

To run the integrated scripting environment (which is a nifty editor for Powershell that only ships in V2), you can always run

PowerShell_Ise

in the run menu

Hope this helps